# TextMate: Bundle to wrap selected text with php commenting

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I am new to TextMate, and so far I am loving it!

Prior to TextMate, I was using Dreamweaver.

Dreamweaver has a nice feature where you select your text, and wrap it with php commenting. `<?php /* */?>`. This was especially useful for temporarily wrapping large blocks of code which already contained html commenting.

E.g. >

```
<?php /*
<div class="container">
<p>My Paragraph</p>
</div><!--End container-->

[...]

<div class="container">
<p>My Paragraph</p>
</div><!--End container-->
*/ ?>
```

Is there already a bundle for this?

I think this would be a good and maybe even standard bundle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already figured this out, there is.  Command+/ will comment selected text in any language you are programming in.